# I am stuck at a point in RAG based langchain application. I want to use Langserve for hosting the application. I am unable to dynamically give inputs

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model

```
#Previously I have initialized a retriever which has the document contents.
docs = retriever_llm.get_relevant_documents("What does finance accounts contain?")
res = []
for doc in docs:
  res.append(doc.page_content)

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("Generate the output: "+ f"{res}"+"strictly in {lang}")
add_routes(
    app,
    prompt | llm,
    path="/custom",
)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

#now I want to use langserve and Instead of giving the question inside retriever.get_relevant_documents function in a static manner, I want to give it dynamically as input in the langserve application. Then I want to pass this input to retriever to get relevant documents and then translate the documents into given language.
Can anyone help me out in doing this?

```
docs = retriever_llm.get_relevant_documents("What does finance accounts contain?")
res = []
for doc in docs:
  res.append(doc.page_content)

prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template("Generate the output: "+ f"{res}"+"strictly in {lang}")
add_routes(
    app,
    prompt | llm,
    path="/custom",
)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

I am expecting every input to be given dynamically in langserve playground, since I am new to langserve, I got stuck here. Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use configurabe_alternate